# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_after' was never awaited (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py, python-asyncio

guys. my code gives the error "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_after' was never awaited". I am using my_after and serverQueue functions to create a queue in my music bot. the problem occurs in "voice.play (FFmpegPCMAudio (URL, ** FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after = lambda e: my_after (voice, message))". everything works correctly only when there is one song in the queue. the rest should be automatically loaded from the queue, which does not happen. when one song ends, the next song is not playing due to an error. but if you use the "& skip" command, the next song in the queue will start playing.

```
    async def play(video_link, voice, message):
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(video_link, download = False)
        print(info.get('title'))
        URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after = lambda e: my_after(voice, message))
        voice.is_playing()
        await message.channel.send('**Now playing** - ' + info.get('title'))

queue = []

async def my_after(voice, message):
    coro = await musicQueue(voice, message)
    await asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro).result()

async def serverQueue(voice, message):
    if ( queue != [] and not voice.is_playing() ):
        await play(queue.pop(0), voice, message)

async def skip(voice, message):
    voice.stop()
    await serverQueue(voice, message)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=message.channel.guild)
    if message.content.startswith('&' + 'join'):
        await join(message)
    if message.content.startswith('&' + 'play'):
        arg = message.content[:0] + message.content[6:]
        await join(message)
        voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=message.channel.guild)
        if arg.startswith('https:'):
            video_link = arg
            if voice.is_playing() == False:
                await play(video_link, voice, message)
            else:
                await message.channel.send('added to queue')
                queue.append(video_link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error explains it. You didn't awaited the asynchronous function.

Change this:

```py
after = lambda e: my_after(voice, message))
```

To this:

```py
after = lambda e: asyncio.run(my_after(voice, message))
```

Comment: I tried it at the beginning, but got the error "SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function"

Comment: I edited my answer. Check if this will work.